# How get grand parent text in a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, parent

I have some problems in accessing the text about a grand parent td in table.

When I click on delete, I would like that my function accesses the grand parent text : "fabien" but all I received is undefined.

this is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Name</td> 
      <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody id="tabSelectUser">
      <tr>
         <td> fabien </td>
         <td><a onclick="javascript:aButtonPressed();"> delete</a></td>
      </tr>                                                                                </tbody>                                            
</table>
```

and this is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function aButtonPressed(){
            var prevCell = $(this).parent().prev().text();
            console.log(prevCell);
</script>
```

Comment: so you want the td with the html fabien inside?

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is

Comment: If you want `#tabSelectUser`, you can use `.closest("#tabSelectUser")`..  http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Jquery to bind the click event, then your `$(this)` will work.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
      <td>Name</td> 
      <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody id="tabSelectUser">
      <tr>
         <td> fabien </td>
         <td><a href="#" class="deleteBtn"> delete</a></td>
      </tr>                                                                                </tbody>                                            
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.deleteBtn').click(aButtonPressed);
});

function aButtonPressed(){
    var prevCell = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    console.log(prevCell);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I have a wild guess that he can add users as well, so you should probably add delegation.

Comment: Then he can bind the click, too. New TD with new A + clickEvent

Comment: the console.log doesn't appear don't know why

Comment: my bad it works, I forget to delete some lines in code due to the copy/past, thx guys !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".childclass").parents("eq(numberofnthparent)").text();
```